# Rigged a hand model, flipped it, and now it isn't deforming correctly. What should I do?

Tags: rigging, blenderkit

So I was working on a character model, rigged it, and it worked fine. But I noticed that I had the hands backwards and tried to flip it. Now, it's not deforming properly.

[image]

[image]

The mesh didn't have any weight-painting before or after I flipped the hand, so I don't think that was the issue. Also, the character model is made up of several different meshes, not just one. I'm trying to make a drawing mannequin.

Comment: Looks like a weight paint or vertex group issue. Would you mind sharing your file so that we can have a look at it? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure! Here you go:

https://pasteall.org/blend/2e3036647a524f4c8f20c7791de42ee3

Comment: And here's the original, unflipped file for reference: https://pasteall.org/blend/eabffcc5a0474b6ca0f83a9037f13ddc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the hand objects in *Object* mode and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>, select all the hand bones in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> and you're good:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much!